# Three questions on measurable functions and $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I'm learning about measure theory and $L^P$ spaces and need help with the following questions:

> True or False (justify):
>
> $(1)$ Let $f:(-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable on $(-n, n), \; \forall n \in (0, 1)$. Then $f$ is measurable on $(-1, 1)$.
>
> $(2)$ If $f, g \in L^2 \implies fg \in L^2$.
>
> $(3)$ If $f \in L^2 \big( [1, M] \big),  \; \forall M > 1 \implies f \in L^2 \big( [1, +\infty) \big)$.

**My work:**

$(2)$ The proposition is **false**. Let

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}\chi_{[0, 1]} = g(x).$$

Then

$$fg(x) = \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}} \chi_{[0, 1]} = \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \chi_{[0, 1]}.$$

Therefore

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left|fg(x)\right|^2\, dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right)^2 \chi_{[0, 1]} \, dx = \int_{[0, 1]} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = +\infty.$$

so $fg \notin L^2$ (since the integral is divergent).

However

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left|f\right|^2=\int_\mathbb{R} \left|g\right|^2 = \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}\right)^2 \chi_{[0, 1]} = \int_{[0, 1]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 2$$

so $f, g \in L^2$ (since the integral is convergent).

Is my work correct for $(2)$? Are there any other counterexamples that are more straightforward then the above one?

---

Questions $(1)$ and $(3)$ are confusing me because they both appear extremely simple. My guess is that they are both **true**. For $(1)$, substituting $n=1$ we immediately get that $f$ is measurable on $(-1, 1)$. For $(3)$, since $M$ can reach infinity then it must be that $f \in L^2 \big( [1, +\infty) \big)$. I think I'm missing some key points for questions $(1)$ and $(3)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For (1), you can substitute only $n \in (0, 1)$, and $1 \not \in (0, 1)$. For (3), $M$ will never *reach* infinity, it will just get closer and closer. Consider a constant function $f = 1$ on $[0, \infty)$. It's in $L^2([0, M])$ for any $M$, but is it  in $L^2([0, \infty))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is true, as $f$ is a limit of sequence of functions $f_n$, $f_n = f \cdot \chi_{(-1 + 1/n, 1-1/n)}$, which are all measurable on $(-1, 1)$ by assumption, so $f$ is measurable on $(-1, 1)$ as a limit of functions measurable on $(-1, 1)$. It's also not hard to show that it's measurable directly. For (3), see my comment above. Your argument for (2) looks correct.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. Both your answers were extremely helpful. They also gave me another way of thinking about these problems.